# Keras multi-output data reshape for LSTM model

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have a Keras LSTM model that contains multiple outputs. 
The model is defined as follows:

```
outputs=[]

main_input = Input(shape= (seq_length,feature_cnt), name='main_input')
lstm = LSTM(32,return_sequences=True)(main_input)
for _ in range((output_branches)): #output_branches is the number of output branches of the model
    prediction = LSTM(8,return_sequences=False)(lstm)
    out = Dense(1)(prediction)
    outputs.append(out)

model = Model(inputs=main_input, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='mse')
```

I have a problem when reshaping the output data.
The code for reshaping the output data is:

```
y=y.reshape((len(y),output_branches,1))
```

I got the following error:

> ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays
>   that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected.
>   Expected to see 5 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1
>   arrays: [array([[[0.29670931],
>           [0.16652206],
>           [0.25114482],
>           [0.36952324],
>           [0.09429612]],
>
> ```
>    [[0.16652206],
>     [0.25114482],
>     [0.36952324],
>     [0.09429612],...
> ```

How can I correctly reshape the output data?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how `y` is structured initially. Here I assume that `y` is a single-valued label for each sequence in batch.

When there are multiple inputs/outputs `model.fit()` expects a corresponding list of inputs/outputs to be given. `np.split(y, output_branches, axis=-1)` in a following fully reproducible example does exactly this - for each batch splits a single list of outputs into a list of separate outputs where each output (in this case) is 1-element list:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tf.enable_eager_execution()

batch_size = 100
seq_length = 10
feature_cnt = 5
output_branches = 3

# Say we've got:
# - 100-element batch
# - of 10-element sequences
# - where each element of a sequence is a vector describing 5 features.
X = np.random.random_sample([batch_size, seq_length, feature_cnt])

# Every sequence of a batch is labelled with `output_branches` labels.
y = np.random.random_sample([batch_size, output_branches])
# Here y.shape() == (100, 3)

# Here we split the last axis of y (output_branches) into `output_branches` separate lists.
y = np.split(y, output_branches, axis=-1)
# Here y is not a numpy matrix anymore, but a list of matrices.
# E.g. y[0].shape() == (100, 1); y[1].shape() == (100, 1) etc...

outputs = []

main_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(seq_length, feature_cnt), name='main_input')
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True)(main_input)
for _ in range(output_branches):
    prediction = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(8, return_sequences=False)(lstm)
    out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(prediction)
    outputs.append(out)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=main_input, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse')

model.fit(X, y)
```

You might need to play around with axes as you didn't specify how exactly your data look like.

EDIT:
As author is looking for an answer drawing from official sources, it's mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/functional#models_with_multiple_inputs_and_outputs) (not explicitly though, it only mentions what the Dataset should yield, hence - what kind of input structure `model.fit()` expects):

> When calling fit with a Dataset object, it should yield either a tuple of lists like `([title_data, body_data, tags_data], [priority_targets, dept_targets])` or a tuple of dictionaries like `({'title': title_data, 'body': body_data, 'tags': tags_data}, {'priority': priority_targets, 'department': dept_targets})`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an amount of outputs equal to `output_branches`, your output data must be a `list` with the same amount of arrays.

Basically, if the output data is in the middle dimension as your `reshape` suggests:

```
y = [ y[:,i] for i in range(output_branches)]
```